# 3Dimensional matrix representation in python

Tags: python, matrix

How can I write a `MxNx3` matrix.
where

```
a = matrix(((1.4,),(2.5,),(1.96,),(6.25,),(12.25,)))

resol_val2 = a.shape
```

here `resol_val2` is `(5, 1)`. I want to write a `matrix b` where `b.shape` is `(M,N,3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using numpy, you can just do:

```
>>> a = numpy.array(((1.4,),(2.5,),(1.96,),(6.25,),(12.25,),(10.21)))
>>> m = 2
>>> n = 3
>>> b = a.reshape((m,n,1))
```